# Secure static file with Forms Authentication in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, forms-authentication

We have a site using Forms authentication with Anonymous authentication enabled in IIS7.

However, with above setting, everyone can access static files in this site such as CSS, JavaScript and Html.

If I disable anonymous authentication, users can't access login page since they aren't login yet.

From my understanding, Forms authentication needs to work with Anonymous authentication enabled.

So how can I secured all resource files ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I kinda find the answer.

Base on @Josh's answer, I found this [page](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis-integrated-pipeline) talking about how to use Forms Authentication for the Entire Application.

I think it works like what I want.

1. you need to install Url Authorization functionality
2. Add the following to your web.config

   < system.webServer>

   < modules>

   < remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />

   < add name="FormsAuthenticationModule" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />

   < remove name="UrlAuthorization" />

   < add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />

   < remove name="DefaultAuthentication" />

   < add name="DefaultAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule" />

Answer (score 3):

In order to have every file be secured by forms authentication, route all requests through the asp .net pipeline.  This is not the default behavior of IIS.  For files that are static content, IIS typically hands them out based on the settings described at the site level (i.e. Anonymous, Basic, Windows, Digest).

While you can do what I mentioned, I would be questioning why you would want to do this.  This adds overhead because the .NET pipeline will start processing each file to determine whether or not to serve it up.

Doable, but not recommended.

Comment: We have user's personal images on our server. I don't anyone without authorized access them. Well, I know the best way should be like storing image in database, but it has performance issue.

Comment: Then I would just add the image extension instead of all files to the .NET managed pipeline.  I've done similar things with paid-for documents, like PDFs, and that seems to work fine.  Just don't run the entire site through the pipeline.

Comment: how exactly do you route all requests through the asp .net pipeline ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272447/net-forms-authentication-how-to-limit-access-to-resources-like-pdf-files-to-au and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814128/activate-form-authentication-for-csv-files-in-iis7

Comment: BTW, I thought in IIS7 if I use Integrated Pipeline Mode, everything goes to the same pipeline.

Comment: You're confusing the integrated pipeline of processing a request and the ASP.NET membership pipeline.  Integrated pipeline allows you to add and remove features from IIS's processing of requests.  It has nothing to do with the default security.

Comment: I'm using integrated mode and setting runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to true on the modules tag in my web.config did it for me.